# Firebase Analytics: Can I check if a Firebase Javascript Analytics event was logged before firebase updates?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

UPDATE: I realize I was not as specific enough in this post. Added new details below.

Junior Dev, new to Firebase..

I understand Firebase Analytics can take up to 24 hours to update.

Is it possible to view if events are logged without waiting for Firebase to update?
Is there a way to see the network request going through?

This is a react native project, being developed in Android Studio IDE, using the Firebase analytics JavaScript SDK.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Debug View to view realtime firebase events for debugging purposes.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

If you're on iOS, you could try enabling debug firebase events in xcode:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/ios/events#view_events_in_the_Xcode_debug_console

Personally, I've had a good experience using google analytics instead, which has a realtime view that works well.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, because that seems to be the correct answer.
I am having trouble setting it up.
The docs say to run the terminal command that involves the app's package_name, which I identified and wrote correctly (I'm pretty sure)

But it isn't showing up in DebugView.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if that's not working. Are you using android or ios? I've edited my answer with a few more things to try.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) Chrome extension, that allows you to see everything going out from that browser.

Comment: Hey.  I added some details to this post.